How to embed a star-slash */ inside a @code tag?
I want to embed */* inside a {@code} tag but when I do, the Javadoc tool complains:
error: illegal start of type
{@code */*}.
         ^

This workaround seems to work: {@code *}{@code /*}
but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Using HTML escape sequences (e.g. &#47;) does not work. They do not get decoded into a single character.
